# R axis ticks numbering

Tags: r, svg, plot

Hi i can't understand the nonsense with axis1 that keeps on happening in this plot.
Relevant piece of code (I think).

```
plot.window(xlim=c(-0.5,0.55),ylim=c(-0.5,0.55), asp=1)
axis(1, at=seq(-0.5 , 0.55, by=0.05), lwd=1, lwd.ticks=1,pos=-0.5,labels=formatC(seq(-0.5,0.55,by=0.05),1, format="f"))
axis(2, at=seq(-0.5 , 0.55, by=0.05), lwd=1, lwd.ticks=1,pos=-0.5,labels=formatC(seq(-0.5,0.55,by=0.05),1, format="f"))
```

The result as output from plotted to RSvgDevice:

[image]

As you can see the Axis2 has worked out as expected, but alas the Axis 1 which has all the same code does not work as I thought it would.

Edit: It seems that the problem is with RSvgDevice library - if I just plot it to plot window things look as expected and also the built-in SVG output works as expected. (The built in SVG device has other issues for me  - such as presenting text as glyphs - so I would still like to use RSVGDevice - or does anybody have a recommendation to svg output that will keep text as fonts)

Comment: When I run your code (after running `plot.new`) I get fairly sensible results. I would check that you aren't calling any other plotting commands that might be altering the axis. Also, I would check the output from your `formatC` call in isolation. Are you sure that's what you intended?

Comment: Seems to be the trouble with library(RSvgDevice). When I just plot the commands there I'll get reasonable results as expected. In case I plot it to devSVG(file="out.svg") It messes it up as shown in the picture. The R built-in svg output works out also fine svg(file="out") - alas the standard svg will put out the symbols as glyphs/paths not fonts (which will mess up combining it with other svg-s etc.)